# Halting program explained

Tags: algorithm, computation-theory, halting-problem

I am trying to understand why is it impossible to write a program H that can check whether another program P on a specific input I will halt or not (Halting problem), but i am unable to get a clear idea of it.

Though intuition says that if this program H tries to run a program P which is not going to halt, then H itself will go into a loop. But i dont think this is the idea behind the proof.

Can anybody explain the proof in simple layman terms?

Comment: Have you read any of the numerous existing expositions on the topic? If so, which, and what was unclear about it to you?

Answer (score 4):

The idea behind the proof is by contradiction.

Assume there is a Halting Problem Machine `M` that solves the Halting problem, and yields `0` if some input program won't finish, and `1` if it will. `M` is guaranteed to finish.

Create a new machine `H`.

`H` runs `M` with the input of `H` (itself), and if `M` answers 1 - get into endless loop, otherwise - stop.

Now, what will happen if you run `M` on input `H`?

If the answer is `1` - than it is wrong, since `H` runs `M`, and will get to infinite loop.

If the answer is `0` - it is also wrong, since `H` will stop.

So, it is contradicting the assumption that `M` is correct - and thus there is no such `M`.

---

Intuitively - it is like saying  there is no such thing as an oracle, because if "you" tell me you're an oracle, I ask you - which arm am I going to raise? 

Then, I will wait for your answer - and do the opposite - which contradicts the claim that the oracle is indeed an oracle.

Comment: [Pet peeve](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/319926) of mine: This is not really a proof by contradiction (though almost always presented as one). Like other diagonal arguments, it *directly and constructively*, for any total TM, creates a program such that the total TM accepts said program iff the program diverges. The assumption that this total TM decides the halting problem is only used *after* this construction to conclude "no TM decides HP", but that can also be derived from "for all TMs, there is a program in HP rejected by the TM or vice versa".

Comment: Or you will raise the *predicted* arm and become psychedelically trapped in endless loop of *no free will*.

Answer (score 3):

Turing used [proof by contradiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction) for this (aka reduction to absurdity):

The idea is to assume there **is** actually such a machine `H` that given any program `p` and an input `i` will tell us weather `p` stops.

Given such `H`, we can modify it and create a new machine.
We'll add another part after `H`'s output such that if `H` outputs yes, our machine will loop infinitely,
and if `H` outputs no, our new machine will halt.
We'll call our new machine `H+`.

Now, the paradox occurs when we feed `H+` to itself (as both program `p` and input `i`).

That's because if `H+` *does halt*, we get a yes answer (from the `H` part), but then it *loops forever*.
However, if `H+` *doesn't halt*, we get a no answer (from the `H` part), but then it *halts*.

---

This is explained very nicely in this [computerphile episode](https://youtu.be/macM_MtS_w4).